# How To Mount Directory Of Conainter Into Another After containers are run?

Tags: docker, nginx, mount

I have angular app, which is built when container is run as shown in `Dockerfile`, that's built from two images.

```
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/banax_education_platform
WORKDIR /usr/src/banax_education_platform

RUN apk add git
COPY package*.json /usr/src/banax_education_platform/
RUN npm i

COPY . /usr/src/banax_education_platform

RUN npm i -g @angular/cli && npm run-script build


FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY /nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/banax_education_platform/dist/edu-app /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

So first of all, it fetches node image and build the app with all requirments. and then it fetches another image of nginx and creates server block to show the app. Now I want to split both images, so one container holds angular app and second does nginx reverse proxy.

Came up with this `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
 nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  container_name: angular-nginx
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  depends_on:
   - web
 web:
  build: ./angular
  container_name: angular-app
  ports:
   - "8000"
```

But the issue is, I want this task: 
`COPY --from=builder /usr/src/banax_education_platform/dist/edu-app /usr/share/nginx/html` to be done via docker-compose, cause now I have 2 Dockerfiles, one for angular, and one for nginx, so I don't know how to link that angular container's directory with nginx container. Someone has any idea?

Comment: mount both with the same directory and serve your app from that directory and another thing you can do is to link both containers. add this task in your entry point of the required contianer COPY --from=builder /usr/src/banax_education_platform/dist/edu-app /usr/share/nginx/html

Comment: Why would you need the build artifacts of your Angular app in the container of the reverse proxy? This doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: how exactly?? App is built while building the image... so content is dynamic and will be copied after it's generated.

Comment: @bellackn then how to serve it from ngunx /var/www/html dir?

Answer (score 2):

In a typical Web application, you run some sort of packager (for instance, [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org)) that "compiles" your application down to a set of static files.  You then need some Web server to send those files to clients, but nothing runs that code on the server side once it's built.

This matches the multi-stage Docker image that you show in the question pretty well.  The first stage only builds artifacts, and once it's done, nothing ever runs the image it builds.  (Note for example the lack of `CMD`.)  The second stage `COPY --from=build` the static artifacts it builds, and that's it.

Since there's no actual application to run in the first stage, it doesn't make sense to run this as a separate Docker Compose service or to otherwise "split this up" in the way you're showing.

If you don't mind having multiple build tools, one thing you can do is to treat the packaged application as "data" from the point of view of Nginx (it doesn't know anything about the content of these files, it just sends data over the network).  You can pick some directory on your host and mount that into the Nginx container

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.12-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

and then `npm run-script build` on your host system when you need to rebuild and redeploy the application.

Comment: Actually, I've got to deploy this in cloud, so all I have to do is build and image, push it on public repo & then deploy them via docker-compose. So scenario is clear to me, the build needs to be done inside image via Dockerfile, and then those images be linked through docker-compose. So can you suggest any easy-to-implement strategy that would speed up this delivery?

Comment: Use a multi-stage build like you had originally; all the content will be in the built image.  Or host your Web application and static assets somewhere that's not Docker, since it is all just static files at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a conceptual misunderstanding. I'm not familiar with Angular, but here's how I would approach this (not tested).

The reverse proxy itself does not need the compiled files that you generate in your Dockerfile. This container (`web` in your case) is just there to pass HTTP(S) requests to the correct endpoint (which is another webserver, let's call it `app`). `app` itself is an Nginx webserver that serves your Angular application.

So, what you would have to do is something like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./config/with/proxy/rules:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  app:
    build: ./path/to/your/dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./path/to/nice/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - web
```

The config file of the first volume would have to include all the proxy rules that you need. Basically, something like this should occur somewhere:

```
location / {
      proxy_pass http://app:8000;
}
```

That's all your reverse proxy has to know.

Comment: what's the use of this line: volumes:
      - ./path/to/nice/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf in app section of docker-compose? can't it be skipped??

Comment: This is the configuration file that Nginx would need to correctly serve your compiled Angular application. If there is no need for such a file, you can skip it. Again, I'm not familiar with Angular. :)

Comment: actually the build command collects some sort of static content to show over web. So it gathers all the content like in dist/edu-app. It has no conf needed but in your solution it needs the app to be running, not sure if it does. nginx needs to reversse proxy from that dist/adu-adpp directory.

Comment: It might be completely sufficient if you copy the compiled files to `/usr/share/nginx/html`. The Nginx in there will then show these files and there is no need to tinker with the config file. Just try it out and skip this line.